# How to get for each column the max value of a date

Tags: postgresql

How to get for each column the max value of a date.

Hello, sorry for my english i will do a brief resumen of my problem.

I am using postgresql, I have one table with some columns, the importants are:
A, B, C, and D, I have another one with the date(F).

I would like to do for each a,b and c(in conjunction) get the value of D with the date(F) is the max value for a,b and c.

Any idea?

Comment: "Another one" means "another table" as Igor Romanche assumed, or "another column"?

Comment: Posting a sample of your data would certainly help. I tried to make one from your question and I failed.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT GREATEST(A,B,C)
FROM table1
```

It will give you the greatest of `A,B,C`. Then:

```
SELECT GREATEST(A,B,C), D
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON GREATEST(A,B,C) = F
```

Details: [GREATEST](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead..

```
with cte as (
  select 1 as A, 1 as B, 1 as C, 'Hello' as D, '12/1/2012'::date as F
  union select 1,2,1,'Hello2','12/2/2012'
  union select 1,1,1,'Hello3','12/5/2012'
)
select a.*
from cte a
join (
    select A,B,C, MAX(F) F
    from cte
    group by A,B,C
) b
  on a.A = b.A
  and a.B = b.B
  and a.C = b.C
  and a.F = b.F
```

Comment: why you are using a some_agggregate_function(D)?

Comment: thanks for your reply. the problem with your code is when B or C has another value, is not shown, for example:

A B C D      F
1 1 1 Hello  12/01/2012
1 2 1 Hello2 12/02/2012
1 1 1 Hello3 12/05/2012

I would like that the result of my query should be:

A B C D      F
1 2 1 Hello2 12/02/2012
1 1 1 Hello3 12/05/2012

the first record have the same A,B and C than the third record, but the max date is the Hello3.